# how to open password protected 7zip archive on OSX

Tags: macos, zip

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to open password protected 7zip archive. I have the password but cant seem to find an application to open it. So far I have tried the following applications:

- Zipeg
- Stuffit Expander
- 7zx
- ExpressZip
- The Unarchiver

I would prefer any free applications or solutions if possible

Running OS 10.6.8

Comment: The outdated version of The Unarchiver that came installed by default on earlier versions of macOS do not support 7zip with passwords. However, The Unarchiver has supported encrypted 7zip files for some time. Delete the old version, and [install the current version](https://theunarchiver.com/), and you will be good to go, just as @Cezary suggests.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the command line. One way would be to:

1. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)
2. Install 7zip: `brew install p7zip`
3. Extract the archive in question: `7za x archive.7z`

You will be asked to enter the password.

```
7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs x64)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 520 bytes (1 KiB)

Extracting archive: archive.7z

Enter password (will not be echoed):
--
Path = archive.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 520
Headers Size = 200
Method = LZMA2:12 7zAES
Solid = -
Blocks = 1

Everything is Ok

Size:       417
Compressed: 520
```

Comment: use ```7z x Myfile.7z``` to keep the directory structure - https://superuser.com/questions/521690/extract-a-7z-on-ubuntu-keeping-the-directory-structure-intact/521708

Comment: @BillyChen Very good point. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The [Keka app](https://www.keka.io/en/) can compress and uncompress 7z format, with support for passwords too.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for a solution and **The Unarchiver** worked for me. It's free to download from App Store on macOS (I'm on Mojave).

Comment: OP says this does not work

Comment: @Mark Maybe the App got updated? Cezary, can you provide some more details, such as a screenshot of the password dialogue?

Comment: +1 @mmmmmm The outdated version of The Unarchiver that came installed by default on earlier versions of macOS do not support 7zip with passwords. However, The Unarchiver has supported encrypted 7zip files for some time. Delete the old version Apple felt the need to distribute, and [install the current version](https://theunarchiver.com/), and you will be good to go, just as Cezary suggests.